# Allow user to type a paragraph using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typing, iusertype

Is there a way to create a box that allows the user to type a paragraph into? I'm hoping to save the user's input.

Comment: Can't you use an HTML `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 3):

`<textarea>Type your stuff here</textarea>`?

Whitespace will be sent to the server, and presumably saved. However, to make it appear as such in the output:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">
Look at me!

See? No BR tags and yet I'm on a new line!

                    Also spaces. SPAAAAAAAAAAACE!
</div>
```

Comment: As for the `hoping to save the paragraphs` part, read up on server-side languages such as PHP or ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<textarea id="someid" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
```

Won't this work?